# jQuery get value from select then change css of a div

Tags: jquery, select, html, background

I've been trying to use this example but for the life of me I cannot get it working.
[Change background of Div from select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764413/change-background-of-div-from-select)

Any input to help me get moving along will be very appreciated

```
<script>
#changemybg {
       background: url(images/default.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
</scipt>

<div id="changemybg"></div>

<select name="change" id="backgrounds">
<option>bg</option>
<option>bg1</option>
<option>bg2></option>
</select>
```

bg = background.jpg
bg1 = background1.jpg
bg2 = background2.jpg

Answer (score 5):

The way you were storing the mappings wasn't very flexible. I have stored them as an object.

If you named them `bg`, `bg2`, etc, and didn't scope them, you'd need to access them as `window['bg' + i]` which is messy.

```
var bg = {
  'bg': 'background.jpg',
  'bg1': 'background1.jpg',
  'bg2': 'background2.jpg' 
};

$('#backgrounds').change(function() {
   var background = $(this).find('option:selected').text();

   if ( ! background in bg) {
       return;
   } 

   $('#changemybg').css({
      'backgroundImage': 'url(' + bg[background] + ')'
   });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/56ULy/).

Alternatively, you could store the filename in the `value` attribute of each `option` element and simply assign the `backgroundImage` to `$(this).val()`.

Also, you are trying to set styles inside a `script` element. That won't work; what you want is a `style` element.

Comment: Ah! thankyou for pointing that out, I was creating these forms in a loop and totally forgot to add the value <noob mistake="true"> if the value name was the same as the option, what would the code above be like?

Comment: @William Drop the `bg`, `background` variables and associated code and just set the `backgroundImage` property to `$(this).val()` as per the mention above.

Answer (score 3):

Test Below Code :

```
$("#backgrounds").change(function()
{
    var val = $(this).val();
    $("#changemybg").css("background-image",val);
});
```

and Change your select to this :

```
<select name="change" id="backgrounds">
<option value="background1.jpg">bg</option>
<option value="background2.jpg">bg1</option>
<option value="background3.jpg">bg2></option>
</select>
```