# jQuery event if dropdown value =

Tags: jquery

How can I change this to only execute the function if a dropdown is selected to "No"

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dropdown_1").change(function () { 
        $("#textbox_1").val(1);
        $("#textbox_2").val("Classic");
        $("#textbox_3").val(1);
    });
});
```

Right now, it works no matter when you change it to.
I only want the above to happen if dropdown_1 is selected to No

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5774999/1481489

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick, assuming of course you are dealing with <select id="dropdown_1">

```
$(function () {
    $("#dropdown_1").change(function () { 
        if($(this).val() == "No") {
            $("#textbox_1").val(1);
            $("#textbox_2").val("Classic");
            $("#textbox_3").val(1);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in a condition that checks the dropdown's `val()`.

Alternatively, bail out early. I like this because it can keep indentation down, and you can eliminate many of the *do-not-continue* cases, allowing the latter of your function's body handle the *happy* case.

```
if ($(this).val() != "No") {
    return;
}
```